# How to start glassfish server using ant?

Tags: ant, glassfish

I need to stop the glassfish server, deploy my war into the glassfish and then start it again using ant.

I can successfully copy the war and make necessary configuration changes using ant tasks. But how do I stop and start the glassfish server using ant?

Basically I would want to execute the startserv.bat file in /glassfish/bin using ant.

Please help

**Edit**

This is what I have tried so far.

```
<project name="Start Server" basedir="." default="startServer">

    <target name="startServer">
        <exec dir="G:\Program Files\glassfish3\glassfish\bin" executable="cmd.exe" os="Windows XP"> 
            <arg value="startserv.bat"/> 
        </exec>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`exec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task to start/stop server

**Update:**
You missing `/c` switch which used to run `.bat` files on Windows

```
<target name="startServer">
  <exec dir="G:\Program Files\glassfish3\glassfish\bin"
        executable="cmd.exe"
        os="Windows XP">
    <arg value="/c"/> 
    <arg value="startserv.bat"/> 
  </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Your code trying to run `cmd.exe` without instructing it to run `startserv.bat`, you should [use arguments like `/c` or `/k` for `cmd.exe`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true) to run commands that way (which is described in `exec` task documentation (with example).